# Альтернативный синтаксис массива С++

Tags: c++, массивы, коллекции, синтаксис

Как я могу по иному написать операторы `[]` и `{}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не могу пока оставлять комментариев, потому напишу ответ: диграфы и триграфы использовались в ситуации, когда клавиатура не имела нужных символов (ISO 646). Триграфы уже не поддерживаются, диграфы все еще с нами.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432443/why-are-there-digraphs-in-c-and-c

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]